# Recursive function for outputing string

Tags: c, recursion, c-strings, post-increment

I have a following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void recursion(char *ptr) {
    if(*ptr!='J') recursion(ptr++);
    printf("%c",*ptr);
}


void main() {
    char v[]="!zenaJ";
    char *ptr=v;
    recursion(ptr);
}
```

I would like to return Janez! trough the recursive function. I don't have any errors when compiling. When I run the program I get an error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect `recursion(ptr++);` to do?

Comment: To increase the pointer and go to the next char. It actually works while I don't use recursion.

Comment: Do you know the very important difference between `ptr++` and `++ptr`?

Comment: The format string `"%c%"` is invalid. I assume you mean `"%c"`.

Comment: Thank you for very constructive answers! Now I know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing recursively the same pointer

```
if(*ptr!='J') recursion(ptr++);
```

because the value of the post-increment expression `ptr++` is the value of the pointer before its incrementing.

The function written in C can look the following way

```
void recursion( const char *ptr ) 
{
    if ( *ptr )
    {
        recursion( ptr + 1 );    
        putchar( *ptr );
    }
}
```

In C++ the function can look the following way

```
std::ostream & recursion( const char *ptr, std::ostream &os = std::cout ) 
{
    if ( *ptr )
    {
        recursion( ptr + 1 );    
        os << *ptr;
    }

    return os;
}
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

and in C++ it can be declared like

```
int main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The increment of ptr occurs only *after* the recursive call for `recursion`.
A simple fix should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void recursion(char *ptr) {
    if (*ptr != 'J')
    {
        char c = *ptr;
        ptr++;
        recursion(ptr);
        printf("%c",c);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%c", 'J');
    }
}


void main() {
    char v[]="!zenaJ";
    char *ptr=v;
    recursion(ptr);
}
```